# Trying to hide rows in Excel based on specific criteria, for multiple sheets

Tags: vba, excel, hide, zero

So I'm working with this file that I put a ton of inputs in, and it varies what inputs I place within the file. After I finalize all the inputs, if a category in the output tabs is still blank or the subtitle for the category is **OPEN** (Meaning I never assigned a section to that subtitle, I want it to hide that row and do that for multiple output sheets.

The current code I have is:

```
Sub Group_And_Hide()
'
' Group_And_Hide Macro
'

'
'Define Variables
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim rowCount As Integer, currentRow As Integer
    Dim firstZeroValueRow As Integer, lastZeroValueRow As Integer
    Dim CurrentRowValue As String
    Dim neighborColumnValue1 As String
    Dim NGV2 As String
    Dim NGV3 As String
    Dim NGV4 As String
    Dim NGV5 As String
    Dim CheckColumn As Integer


'Select Balance Sheet
Sheets("Balance Sheet").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Turns off screen uppdating while running

 'Establish the page range
 Set myRange = Range(D3, W126)
 rowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, myRange.Column).End(xlUp).Row

'Reset the rows and Check
 firstZeroValueRow = 0
 lastZeroValueRow = 0
 CheckColumn = 9

 'Commands
  For currentRow = 1 To rowCount
        CurrentRowValue = Cells(currentRow, myRange.Column).Value
        neighborColumnValue = Cells(currentRow, myRange.Column - 1).Value

      If Cells(currentRow, CheckColumn).Value Like "**OPEN**" Then
          'If First Cell is Open, and first blank row hasn't been assigned
          If firstZeroValueRow = 0 Then
              firstZeroValueRow = currentRow
          End If
      ElseIf Not Cells(currentRow, CheckColumn).Value Like "**OPEN**" Then
          'if the cell is not Open and the row right values are 0,
          'and firstBlankRow hasn't been assigned, then this is the      firstBlankRow
            'to consider for grouping
            If (Cells(currentRow, CheckColumn + 3).Value And Cells(currentRow, CheckColumn + 4).Value And Cells(currentRow, CheckColumn + 5).Value And Cells(currentRow, CheckColumn + 6).Value = 0) Then

                firstZeroValueRow = currentRow
             ElseIf Cells(currentRow, CheckColumn + 3).Value And Cells(currentRow, CheckColumn + 4).Value And Cells(currentRow, CheckColumn + 5).Value And Cells(currentRow, CheckColumn + 6).Value <> 0 And firstZeroValueRow <> 0 Then
                'if firstBlankRow is assigned and this row has a value with a neighbor
               'who isn't 0, then the cell one row above this one is to be considered
              'the lastBlankRow to include in the grouping
              lastZeroValueRow = currentRow - 1
          End If
      End If

      'if first AND last blank rows have been assigned, then create a group
      'then reset the first/lastBlankRow values to 0 and begin searching for next
    'grouping
    If firstZeroValueRow <> 0 And lastZeroValueRow <> 0 Then
        Range(Cells(firstZeroValueRow, myRange.Column), Cells(lastZeroValueRow, myRange.Column)).EntireRow.Select
        Selection.Group
        firstZeroValueRow = 0
        lastZeroValueRow = 0
    End If
Next




ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=1 'Minimize all the groups
Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'Turns on screen updating when done


End Sub
```

So basically I would hope to repeat that code by selecting the next sheet say "Income Statement"

What I hope for the resulting code to do is take a file that looks like this:

```
Assets:
 Current Assets    4000    50000   60000
 Fixed Assets      100     8000    500
Liabilities:
 C. Liab.          -       -       -
 LT Liab.          -       -       -
Equity:
 Capital Stock     4100    58000   60500
 **OPEN**          -       -       -
 Net Income        (300)   (100)   (500)
 RE               300       100    500
```

And it would end up looking like this:

```
Assets:
 Current Assets    4000    50000   60000
 Fixed Assets      100     8000    500
Liabilities:
Equity:
 Capital Stock     4100    58000   60500
 Net Income        (300)   (100)   (500)
 RE               300       100    500
```

So I need to be hiding the zero values (the dashes) not blanks.

Looking for any help with this code thank you.

Comment: Are you just looking to repeat the script above for all your sheets?  Or, do you need help with hiding rows?  Also, I noticed that you are grouping rows... if you have a 'hidden' row within your group, it will become 'unhidden' when you collapse / expand it.  Please clarify

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. To clarify, I don't want to actually "Hide" rows per say, but I want to group them and collapse them so they are hidden from view, and then yes I want to be able to repeat this script for multiple pages. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As CRUTER commented, grouping the rows would defeat the purpose of hiding the rows.  Any hidden rows would be shown when you open the group.

If you just want to hide the rows on the output and forget about them, then I'd recommend just iterating through the rows and hiding each one that meets your criteria.  Something like:

```
For RowIndex = 1 To LastRow
    If (Not IsCategoryRow(RowIndex)) Then
        If (IsRowEmpty(RowIndex)) Then
            Rows(RowIndex).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    End If
 Next RowIndex
```

Define `LastRow` to be the end of your output, and insert your own logic in place of `IsCategoryRow` and `IsRowEmpty`.  If your output format is consistent, you can probably define a category row as anything with a ":" character at the end (e.g. "Assets:", "Liabilities:", etc.) and just skip to the next row.